# i keep on getting 404 error for my static file in django 4.1.3

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

currently trying to implement Dialogflow cx chatbot into a website using Django and Kommunicate
watched a Youtube vid and followed it
everything works until the last part when trying to get script.js
the website just cant get the script.js part

DEBUG = False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

tried online solutions but didn't work for me
ps its my first time asking a question on stack overflow

```
MyProject
|    
+-- MyApp
|  |  
|  +-- _pychache_ //folder contains untouched stuff
|  +-- migrations //folder contains untouched stuff
|  +-- static //contains script.js
|  +-- templates //contains index.html 
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- admin.py
|  +-- apps.py
|  +-- models.py
|  +-- tests.py
|  +-- urls.py
|  +-- views.py
|
+-- MyProject 
|  |  
|  +-- _pychache_ //folder contains untouched stuff
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- asgi.py
|  +-- settings.py
|  +-- urls.py
|  +-- wsgi.py
|    
+-- db.sqlite3
|
+-- manage.py
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # added
    # url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    # url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('MyApp.urls'))
]
```

urls.py in MyApp folder

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
]
```

Comment: can you put your urls.py file here? Need to check that first.

Comment: @DivyaPrakash yes, sorry. its done :D

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this static config in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static'] # comment this (if DEBUG = False)
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static' # Add Static Root
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work :(